# show diagram just in first use in android programing

Tags: android

I want use an alert diagram in my first activity android programming that show for one time in first time that user open application 
can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare a `boolean` along the line of:

```
    private static boolean isFirstLaunch = true;
```

Then, display your alert diagram and anything else you need to do on first launch, and turn the `boolean` to false:

```
    if (isFirstLaunch == true) {
     //call dialog box or the like here
     isFirstLaunch = false;
    }
```

Subsequently, when the activity resumes, it checks that the `boolean` is now false, and therefore will not display the dialog box anymore. Please note that this approach works for an activity that is in session. If it is forcefully terminated and relaunched, the dialog box will display again. To rectify that, you can save your boolean value in a `SharedPreferences` and check the `SharedPreferences` each time the app launches.

Comment: tanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep a boolean variable in your SharedPrefences file. First time when the user  opens your app , you retrieve the value of that boolean from the SharedPreferences and it is false, So you show the alert diagram and change that boolean value in the preferences to true. Next time when the user comes to your app , you again check the value of the boolean variable. You find its value true, so you don't show the diagram.

See If it helps!!!!

Comment: tanks for your answer :)